# Laravel 4 - Routes not resetting to root

Tags: url, laravel, routes

I'm having an issue where when I go to a route with an href such as

> example.com/user/foo

and then click on a link with a href such as

> example.com/cart/bar

the URL sets to

> example.com/user/cart/bar

and I get an error. The issue is the URL is not resetting to the root directory, but keeps the subdirectory('user') in the URL.

Here's a sample of a link to a user route:

```
<li><a href="/user/{{ Auth::user()->username }}">{{ Auth::user()->firstName }} {{ Auth::user()->lastName }}</a></li>
```

and the route:

```
Route::get('/user/{username}', array(
    'before' => 'auth',
    'as' => '/user/{username}',
    'uses' => 'ProfileController@user'
    ));
```

the resulting call to the view:

```
return View::make('profile.user')
            ->with('user', $user);
```

at this point, the URL is:

> example.com/user/john_smith

But then, let's say I want to view my shopping cart which has an href of:

```
<li><a href="store/cart">Cart</a></li>
```

and the route:

```
Route::get('store/cart', array(
    'as' => 'get-cart',
    'uses' => 'StoreController@getCart'
    ));
```

the resulting call to the view:

```
return View::make('store.cart')->with('products', Cart::contents());
```

the URL should be:

> example.com/store/cart

but instead it's

> example.com/user/store/cart

and I get a 'NotFoundHttpException'

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `url()` helper function to generate an absolute url, for example:

```
<li><a href="{{ url('store/cart') }}">Cart</a></li>
```

[Check the helper functions](http://laravel.com/docs/4.0/helpers#urls).